# realm: using in CRNA app

Tags: react-native, realm

I want to use Realm in CRNA (Create React Native App) app. After installing this package, I have to use this command to link it to the ReactNative.

react-native link realm

But after running it, I get this error:
"`react-native link` can not be used in Create React Native App projects. If you need to include a library that relies on custom native code, you might have to eject first."

Is there any way to use Realm in CRNA app without ejecting?
I noticed [this link](http://react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/155) but has it ever been changed?

Comment: I believe that the issue is Expo not supporting Realm

Comment: @geisshirt could you point to some documentation? see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431016/installing-realm-with-create-react-native-app) too

Comment: @SumiStraessle https://forums.expo.io/t/is-realm-support-for-expo-coming/31